# Copy all files beginning with a certain letter

Tags: android

What I am trying to do is copy files from one folder to another. However, the twist is i was to copy all files from one folder which begin with say 123 and anything can follow.

For example i have a folder with 3 files, 123__sdf.jpg, 123034.jpg and 321.jpg.
I only want to copy the first two but how do I select them only. Because this application is dynamic the files can change thats why i only want to be able to select all files which begin with 123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you want to create a file pointing to the directory. Then, you can use the `list` method to get the list of files inside the directory. You can then use `startsWith` to check whether they start with 123 or not.

```
File dir = new File("/the/dir/");
if( dir.isDirectory() ){
    String[] files = dir.list();
    for (String string : files) {
        if( string.startsWith("123") ){
            File file = new File(dir, string);
            // do the copy stuff
        }
    }
}
```

`list` method returns a list of strings with files and directories, so you may want to use the `isFile()` method if you only want to copy files.